# How do I create a transparent hole in Adobe Illustrator

Tags: adobe-illustrator

I am designing some key tags and am VERY new to illustrator. I currently just have a circle placed where I would like the hole, is there a way I can "cut that circle out so there is just a hole in the design that is transparent behind it?

Comment: You would be using pathfinder. I think this question is a little too basic for this site. You should be looking at YouTube tutorials for pathfinder before asking a question that simple,

Comment: Hi user112675, welcome to GDSE and thanks for your question. If you want to know more about the site, please see the [tour](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/tour) and the [help] or ping one of us in the [chat] once your reputation is sufficient (20). Keep contributing and enjoy the site!

Answer (score 2):

If you want to make the area transparent without destructively or practically affecting any of the other artwork you can use a knockout group. If you want to cut through *everything* so there is nothing visible below, you can use a *page* knockout group.

1. Make sure your shape is above everything else
2. Give the shape a fill and set its opacity to 0%
3. Check "Page Knockout Group" from the panel menu...

[image]

If you only want to cut through specific parts of your artwork (e.g. you need a background image), you can use a regular knockout group, which you define on the group or layer you want to cut through. You can see an example here:

- [How do I make an object fill transparent without showing objects below in Illustrator?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/a/70412/52050)

Comment: This will also *knockout* from everything (even other layers underneath), (So you can't potentially have an item behind that you would want to show)

Comment: @שelz sure, you can use a regular knockout group if you don’t want to cut through everything (see edit)

Answer (score 1):

The easy method:
Select the circle, Object > Path > Divide Objects Below.

[image]

Then click the circle again and delete: Hey presto...

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Use the pathfinder tool:

Google it or youtube it:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BZoDaE2z8v4

Answer (score -3):

1. Create a circle.
2. Increase the strength of the stroke to whatever fits your imagination.
3. Make the fill *No color* and the stroke the desired color.
4. If anything looks good, go to *Object → Path → Contour Line* (or *Stroke Line*).
5. Ungroup the result with *Object → Ungroup.*